# Where is my mistake?: If $A, B$ are disjoint and compact subsets of $\mathbb{R}$, then their distance is positive.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, proof-verification

Can you please tell me where my line of reasoning goes wrong? I suspect my proof is incorrect because I do not appear to use compactness anywhere.

Let $A$ and $B$ be disjoint compact subsets of $\mathbb{R}$. Prove that $$\text{dist}(A,B) = \inf \{|y - x|: y \in B, x \in A \} > 0.$$

My attempt at the solution:

Assume that $\text{dist}(A,B) = 0$. 
Since $\{|y - x|: y \in B, x \in A\}$ is bounded from below and from the definition of infimum, we have that for all $\epsilon > 0$ there exists an $s \in \{|y - x|: y \in B, x \in A\}$ (there exists $y_1 \in B$ and $x_1 \in A$ with $|y_1 - x_1| = s$), such that $s < 0 + \epsilon$. This contradicts the fact $A$ and $B$ are disjoint, hence $\text{dist}(A,B) > 0$.

Please do not give away the solution, just let me know why my reasoning is faulty.

Comment: I don't understand the reasoning of "This contradicts the fact ...". If two points are closer then epsilon to each other, it doesn't mean they are equal.

Comment: You are right, I have the quantifiers mixed up. They would be equal if it was: there exists an s such that for all epsilon.

Comment: A nice example, in $\mathbb{R}^2$, is the graph of $xy=1$ and the $x$-axis, they get arbitrarily close together as $x$ increases.

Comment: If $d(A,B) = 0$ then since $A,B$ are compact there are points $a\in A, b \in B$ such that $d(A,B) = |a-b| = 0$ which contradicts disjointedness.

Comment: Your argument can produce a sequence $x_n \in A, y_n \in B$ such that $|x_n-y_n| \to 0$. Use compactness to produce a $,\in A, y \in B$ such that $|a-b| = 0$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I see no reason that having arbitrarily small $|x - y|$ should force a contradiction. Consider the sets $A = \mathbb{N}, B = \pi \mathbb{N}$, and try drawing a picture of your argument. Both are closed, disjoint, and $\operatorname{dist} (A, B) = 0$.

EDIT: Consider especially that your $x_1$ will be $\epsilon$-dependent. So it may make more sense to write $x_k, y_k$ for $|x_k - y_k | < 1/k$.

Answer (score 2):

That for all $\epsilon >0$ there exists $x \in A, y\in B$ such that $|x-y|<\epsilon$ doesn't mean that $A$ and $B$ aren't disjoint. Consider, for example, $\mathbb{Z}$ and $\displaystyle \{(1+ \frac{1}{n^2})n\}_{n \in \mathbb{Z}}$ These are both closed, unbounded sets, and yet for all $\epsilon>0$ we can find points in each set that are $\epsilon-$close.

Your argument is almost complete though. You have to use compactness, as you say. What you said can give you two sequences, $x_n \in A, y_n \in B$, such that $|x_n - y_n| < \frac{1}{n}$. Now use compactness.